# Extending Spring Cloud - Cloud Platform Extensibility

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

After reading the following post I have a few questions:

https://spring.io/blog/2014/08/05/extending-spring-cloud

Imagine that I have implemented my own Spring Cloud (Cloud Platform Extensibility), and after testing in my local machine I want to deploy in different environments.

Assume that:

- My environments have a Docker installation.
- I do not want to install the Cloud Foundry architecture in them.

My questions are:

- What are the requirements for the different environment to work with my own Spring Cloud? i.e. must I install Spring Cloud Foundry architecture in all the environment machines?
- Is Spring Cloud Foundry archictecture compulsory though I have implemented my custom Spring Cloud?
- Must I use commands like "cf" to upload and deploy the services?

Many thanks.

Regards,
Paco.

Comment: That blog post describes what is now spring cloud connectors.

Comment: It is a pleasure to get a reply from @spencergibb :)

My main question is about the mechanism to have my own Spring Cloud Connectors and Docker (Swarm + Registry) together. Do you know any example about that? Is it possible? Imagine that the environments does not have Internet connection

Answer (score 2):

That is an old blog post and I feel it doesn't accurately describe Spring Cloud as it stands today.  It refers to the since renamed [Spring Cloud Connectors](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors) project.

Spring Cloud, built on top of Spring Boot, provides developers an easy way of building "cloud native" and "12 factor" applications.  That essentially boils down to the common patterns found in modern applications such as centralized configuration, service discovery, circuit breakers, etc.  This is cloud agnostic and works well in a variety of environments including AWS and GCP.

So no, Spring Cloud isn't really directly related to Cloud Foundry, however it works nicely there as it does many other places.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, to do a full answer to my previous questions...how to deploy my custom spring cloud without the tools like "cf" from Cloud Foundry? any example in git or blog?

Comment: @pakkk That all depends on where you want to deploy your application to.  Are you using AWS?  If so are you using EC2, Elastic Beanstalk or ECS?  Each of those has a different answer because they all have a different API and/or CLI.

Comment: Thanks again Kyle, I am using Docker (Swarm + Registry) to deploy generated images (inside these images are Spring Boot projects). So, the Swarm+Registry architecture is quite similar than Cloud Foundry, then I am not sure if I should replace all the Docker architecture by Spring Cloud Foundry...

Answer (score 1):

You probably solved your problem, but in case not and for the sake of others i'll post an answer. You can deploy a spring cloud application on docker swarm using `docker compose v3` . As shown in this [repository](https://github.com/binblee/springcloud-swarm/blob/master/README.md) , the command `docker stack deploy -f all-in-one.yml springcloud` deploys the resource specified in `all-in-one.yml` on docker swarm. You can take a look at how `docker stack` works in this [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part5/#add-a-new-service-and-redeploy).